# Is there a way to access '/Click/xxxx' files using web scraping?

Tags: python, pdf, web-scraping

I am currently trying to download a few pdf files from http://annualreports.com/Company/abercrombie-fitch and I am having a problem downloading the 2019 Annual Report. I am currently using

```
response = urllib2.urlopen("http://annualreports.com" + link)
file = open(name, 'wb')
file.write(response.read())
```

where link is '/Click/20415' but this is returning a text file rather than a pdf. Is there a specific way to fix this?

Comment: https://stackabuse.com/download-files-with-python/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another solution, using `requests` module.

```
import requests


url = 'http://annualreports.com/Click/20415'

with requests.get(url, stream=True) as r:
    filename = r.url.split('/')[-1]
    with open(filename, 'wb') as f_out:
        for chunk in r.iter_content(chunk_size=8192):
            if chunk:
                print('.', end='')
                f_out.write(chunk)
```

This saves `NYSE_ANF_2019.pdf` file to your disk.

---

EDIT: Screenshot from PDF in Firefox:

[image]

Comment: What exactly does chunk_size do? Sorry I am relatively new to scraping

Comment: @tvshaw It specifies how many bytes is download from the server before written to local file. See: https://2.python-requests.org/en/master/api/#requests.Response.iter_content

Comment: Thanks for the clarification! The code is returning an empty PDF however- does this have to do with the chunk size being too small?

Comment: @tvshaw What URL returns empty PDF? `'http://annualreports.com/Click/20415'` ?

Comment: That one does but all of the links I have tested on the webpage do as well

Comment: @tvshaw Strange, opening `http://annualreports.com/Click/20415` produces the PDF (I added screenshot from it to my answer). Check if you haven't been blocked (or captcha...): `print(requests.get("http://annualreports.com/Click/20415").text)`

Answer (score 0):

If you use Selenium you could try this:

```
from selenium import webdriver

download_dir = "C:\\Temp\\Dowmload"  # for linux/*nix, download_dir="/usr/Public"
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()

profile = {"plugins.plugins_list": [{"enabled": False, "name": "Chrome PDF Viewer"}], # Disable Chrome's PDF Viewer
               "download.default_directory": download_dir , "download.extensions_to_open": "applications/pdf"}
options.add_experimental_option("prefs", profile)
driver = webdriver.Chrome('//Server/Apps/chrome_driver/chromedriver.exe', chrome_options=options)  # Optional argument, if not specified will search path.

driver.get('http://annualreports.com' + link)
```

If you only want to download the PDF and do not want to do anything on the site, I think it is better to use the method that @[superstew](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8784938/superstew) says. See:

https://stackabuse.com/download-files-with-python/